# How to show valid event handler signature

Tags: visual-studio

In previous versions of Visual Studio (using 2017 now) when coding a Windows Forms app using Visual Basic and creating a method to handle an event I would see the valid signature in the error tooltip. Something like this:

Method 'Private Sub TestMethod(sender As Object, e As string)' cannot handle event 'Event(sender As Object, e As string, x as string)' because they do not have a compatible signature.

In 2017 the message is similar but it leaves off the correct signature after the event name.

[image]

If anyone knows any way to turn the signature help back on I would be very grateful as, if I don't know the sig, I have to go out to the Microsoft site to find it. Definitely not the most efficient process. If there is some other way to quickly bring up the appropriate signature information that would also be welcome. I tried using CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE and the help and but it takes me to a generic dev help page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the red-squiggle under the event, such as **Enter** and type `<Alt><F12>`. That should present a window showing the method signature definition, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Jazimov the window I see when clicking on the event name and then hitting F12 (Alt+F12 shows the same) is different than yours but it still gives me what I need. Thank you!

[image: Show event signature]